# Ensemble of periodic functions orthogonal to their derivative

Tags: orthogonality, signal-processing, periodic-functions

What is the most general form of real periodic functions orthogonal to their derivative ?

Trigonometric functions are an obvious example of such functions (e.g. for $f(x)=\sin(x)$, then $\langle f,f'\rangle=\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}\sin(x) \cos(x) dx=0$), but are these the only periodic functions orthogonal to their derivative ?

Conversely, does the ensemble of periodic functions not orthogonal to their derivative have a name, let alone known generic properties ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Actually, this is the case for any periodic function. Consider $f(x)$ being periodic with period $T$. That is, $f(x+T)=f(x)$. In particular, $f(T)=f(0)$. Then, integrating by parts,

$$\int\limits_0^Tf(x)f'(x)dx = f(x)f(x)\big|_0^T-\int\limits_0^Tf'(x)f(x)dx$$

Thus,

$$2\int\limits_0^Tf(x)f'(x)dx = f(x)f(x)\big|_0^T = f(T)^2-f(0)^2=0$$

Hence

$$\int\limits_0^Tf(x)f'(x)dx = 0$$

Comment: Excellent - looks obvious now ;) Many thanks !

Comment: @ErnestF I was fascinated by this result, too. Looks so simple I'm surprised I didn't know this earlier.

Comment: This now raises another question: are periodical functions the only stationary ones orthogonal to their derivatives ? Another topic in itself probably.

Comment: @ErnestF What do you mean by "stationary"?

Comment: Stationary in the "stationary process" statistical sense.

Comment: @ErnestF Could you be more explicit, please? I don't see how stochastic processes are related to the question.

Comment: I meant finding all (stationary & differentiable) processes $f$ fulfilling $\langle f f'\rangle=0$.

Comment: @ErnestF Yes, I think this is a separate question.